# install dlib with python 3.5 on ubuntu 16 -- how to link proper libboost .so file

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, boost, dlib

I'm trying to install dlib version 19.0 on python 3.5 on a 64-bit ubuntu machine.  So far I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

I downloaded [dlib version 19.0](http://dlib.net/), then

```
tar xvjf dlib-19.0.tar.bz2
cd dlib-19.0
python setup.py install
```

Then I went into python, and tried importing dlib

```
import dlib
```

It gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/nate/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dlib-19.0.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

I know I need to link the dlib to libboost_python-py35.so.1.58.0 (it's in the same /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ directory), I just don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm using anaconda, I was able to use the package I found here: https://anaconda.org/menpo/dlib

And in a terminal, executed:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib=18.18
```

After that it worked!  Thank sweet baby jimmy.